# MAMP no longer prompt for a password and Apache won't start

Tags: macos, apache, mamp

After an upgrade to MAMP 6.7 on macOS Monterey, MAMP no longer prompts for a password and Apache won't start.

At MAMP start:

- MySQL starts
- Apache doesn't start
- I must execute /Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh in Terminal to start Apache

At MAMP stop:

- I must use /Applications/MAMP/bin/stop.sh

Until this update (to 6.7), MAMP asked me for a password every time I started.

I tried several solutions found here. Same problem with port 80 or 8888. At each test, I kill all HTTPD or MYSQLD process. Renaming or deleting envvars does nothing.

It seems that MAMP can't execute startApache.sh.

Edit :
The last update 6.8 solve this issue : https://www.mamp.info/en/release-notes/mac/#v6.8

Comment: Having the same issue with recent update, everything worked until then.

Comment: And what did you do to work ?

Comment: Nothing, just waiting for the fix on their side and running it manually like you are. Seems like new release is out already so hopefully we can solve this one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that MAMP found something about this issue : https://www.mamp.info/en/release-notes/mac/#v6.8